# Rotating on a Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation

I have been struggling for more than a day to get the functionality of selectively rotating a set of tiles that are drawn on a canvas by any number of degrees.  I am just not getting it and finally I am asking for help. I need to be able to rotate any tile from its anchor point (top left, top right point)by any degrees.

The main javascript code that is confusing me is when I determine that the tile needs rotated  in the following:

```
        function drawTile(context, tile,i) {
                            TILE_WIDTH=tile.width;
                            TILE_HEIGHT=tile.height;
     // Draw the tile with rounded corners
                            tile_x_position=tile.x;
                            tile_y_position=tile.y;

    //  determine if the tile is rotated  
                           rotation_angle=tile.plot_rotate;
    //  yes  it needs rotated                   
                            if (rotation_angle != 0){
                            radian_value=(Math.PI/180)*rotation_angle;
    //  get center point of tile to be rotated                        
                            vertical= (tile_y_position+TILE_HEIGHT)/2;
                            horizontal= (tile_x_position+TILE_WIDTH)/2

                            
                            context.translate( tile_x_position, tile_y_position);
                            context.rotate(radian_value);  //  rotate the tile on its center point
     
                           
            }
```

Then I draw the tile.

When done, I reset things as follows:

```
                       if (rotation_angle != 0){
                           
                           context.rotate(-radian_value);
                           context.translate( -tile_x_position, -tile_y_position);
      
                         }
```

You can see that it is not doing what I want it to do by looking at the completed javascript code  in  https://jsfiddle.net/jackmstein/m69sfcrq/1/

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and fixed the code in the link  https://jsfiddle.net/jackmstein/m69sfcrq/5/

It turns out that before you rotate the Canvas, you need to specify the translate reference.   I had it incorrectly set to the center of the tile instead of the left most top corner.

```
                    tile_x_position=tile.x;
                    tile_y_position=tile.y;

    //  determine if the tile is rotated  
                    rotation_angle=tile.plot_rotate;
    //  yes  it needs rotated                   
                    if (rotation_angle != 0){
                    radian_value=(Math.PI/180)*rotation_angle;
   //  get left most  point of tile to be rotated                        
                    radian_value=(Math.PI/180)*rotation_angle;
                    context.translate( tile_x_position, tile_y_position);  
    //set the new point of reference for the canvas to left top
                    context.rotate(radian_value);  //  rotate the tile on the new point
    //  set the points of reference for the tile to be shown based on the rotated canvas 
                    tile_x_position=0;
                    tile_y_position=0;
    }
```

Then when you are done drawing the tile, you reset the Canvas as follows:

```
     if (rotation_angle != 0){

                    
                    context.rotate(-radian_value);  //reset everything back
                    tile_x_position=tile.x;
                    tile_y_position=tile.y;
                    context.translate( -tile_x_position, -tile_y_position);
                   }
```